# Strange behavior with RandomForestClassifier estimators_

Tags: python, tree, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

df = pd.read_csv('musk_clean.csv')
X=df.iloc[:,0:-1]
y=df.iloc[:,-1]
clf=RandomForestClassifier(1)
clf.fit(X,y)
print(clf.score(X,y))
print(clf.estimators_[0].score(X,y))
```

The csv can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6p-IVAybbfJMDk2eVB1WGt2MGc).
Although the random forest consists of only one decision tree, and its accuracy is 0.97, when I check the accuracy of the tree, taken from estimators_, I get accuracy of 0.14.
Seems like something is wrong, since it should be the same decision tree..

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening? How can I get the same accuracy using the tree(s) from estimators_?

Answer (score 2):

**Be careful when using internal sub-predictors on your problems. As this is not the designed case, you should be afraid of losing information.**

With a bit of analysis, you should have found, where this problem is coming from.

A demo:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

df = pd.read_csv('X:\musk_clean.csv')
X=df.iloc[:,0:-1]
y=df.iloc[:,-1]
clf=RandomForestClassifier(1)
clf.fit(X,y)

print('naive')
print(clf.score(X,y))
print(clf.estimators_[0].score(X,y))

print('check preds')
print(clf.predict(X))
print(clf.estimators_[0].predict(X))
```

Output:

```
naive
0.978629887845
0.144437708396
check preds
[ 1.  1.  1. ..., -1. -1. -1.]
[ 1.  1.  1. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
```

Okay: using the internal tree, **you did lose information about the binary-class representation: 1/-1 or 1/0**. So probably sklearn is normalizing this internally and, as mentioned by design, it's not pipelined to the internal classifiers.

This is seen here:

```
print(clf.classes_)
print(clf.estimators_[0].classes_)
```

Output:

```
[-1.  1.]
[ 0.  1.]
```

Another small demo where we just correct this manually:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
forest_preds = clf.predict(X)
print(accuracy_score(y, forest_preds))
tree_preds = clf.estimators_[0].predict(X)
tree_preds[tree_preds == 0] = -1
print(accuracy_score(y, tree_preds))
```

Output:

```
0.977114277054
0.977114277054
```

**Edit:** To my surprise, `classes_` is not read-only. So the following might be the more interesting demo:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

df = pd.read_csv('X:\musk_clean.csv')
X=df.iloc[:,0:-1]
y=df.iloc[:,-1]
clf=RandomForestClassifier(1)
clf.fit(X,y)

tree_clf = clf.estimators_[0]
tree_clf.classes_ = clf.classes_

print(clf.score(X,y))
print(clf.estimators_[0].score(X,y))
```

Output:

```
0.985298575326
0.985298575326
```